# maven2 - how to list all resources repository url from pom file

Tags: java, maven-2, repository, pom.xml, artifactory

I'm looking for something like this:

```
List<URL> urls = listURLFromPOM("c:\pom.xml");

..

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ibatis/ibatis-core/3.0/ibatis-core-3.0.jar
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/camel-activemq/1.1.0/camel-activemq-1.1.0.jar

...
```

Comment: What's the calling context?  A Maven plugin implementation?  Code you're building into a JAR with Maven?  Something else?

Also, a POM can contain URLs in many places.  Which ones do you want to extract?

Comment: I just want to print a remote repository artifact list in elsewhere.
So i can copy it latter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to analyze the dependencies of you POM.

```
mvn dependency:list -DoutputAbsoluteArtifactFilename=true -DoutputFile=dependencies.txt
```

Comment: Use SCP or FTP to transfer the file after the maven call is finished (and don't forget to rate the answer).

Answer (score 5):

A dependency is not aware of its *"source repository"* which might not be unique so you won't be able to get the *"source URL"* of a dependency without actually **resolving it**. One way to do that (without writing code using Maven internal APIs) would be to use [`dependency:purge-local-repository`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html). From the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) documentation:

> - [`dependency:purge-local-repository`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html)  tells Maven to clear all dependency-artifact files out of the local repository, and optionally re-resolve them.

Run that command and redirect the output to a file for post-processing:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository > raw.txt
```

As I just mentioned, if you are using several repositories, you might need to do some post processing to separate the "successful" download from "failed" attempts. Here is a [sample regex](http://www.rubular.com/r/ExEdxJbC0p) on Rubular that might be helpful to implement such a post-processing (I provided some content illustrating the "problem").

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!
I did this on windows to get just the urls...
findstr "Downloading" raw.txt > urls.txt

Comment: @CelinHC: You're welcome. I just updated my answer and posted a link to illustrate a potential problem when using multiple repositories (and how to filter the output).

Comment: This works for me as well, output looks something like: `Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.9.3/jets3t-0.9.3.pom`

However, in case it is not obvious, beware...this will purge your local maven repository!