# Leiningen raises "Tried to use insecure HTTP repository without TLS." but for which dependency?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojars

I'm using Leiningen to run a Clojure project on my Raspberry Pi 3 (running stretch), previously I used version 2.7.1 with no problems, but upgrading to the latest version on lein (2.8.1) I now get this error for some of the dependencies (but not others):

```
Tried to use insecure HTTP repository without TLS
```

However, `lein` doesn't tell me which dependencies are causing problems, so how do I discover which ones cause this error?

Also is it possible to disable this security feature for certain dependencies? I'm only running on a home network so consider this acceptable.

Comment: See the FAQ for this, https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/2.8.1/doc/FAQ.md#faq.

Comment: Perhaps post you :dependencies from project.clj?

Comment: I've read the FAQ but it doesn't say how to discover the problem dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Answer edited after a comment correctly pointed out that the first method was showing only the immediate dependencies.

1. Generate the Maven POM:

   ```
   lein pom
   Wrote .../pom.xml
   ```
2. Following this answer for Java https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270067/561422, use the Maven dependency plugin:

   ```
   mvn dependency:purge-local-repository > raw.txt
   ```

Open `raw.txt` in an editor and search for the string `http:`, that should point you on the right track.

For example with Unix command-line tools:

Unsafe repos (searching for `http:`):

```
grep http: raw.txt
Downloading from example: http://unsafe.example.org
```

Comment: This answers only one of the questions. The pom.xml seems to only show first line deps. So when a dependency relies on an unsafe dependency you won't find it.

Comment: @acidjunk you are right. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: The format of the raw.txt doesn't help you determine which top-level dependency listed in project.clj is the cause. You could use "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true" which will list the missing dependency in a form similar to: "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project lotusflare-funnel: Could not resolve dependencies for project Could not transfer artifact org.clojure:clojure:pom:1.3.0-alpha2 from/to clojure (http://build.clojure.org/releases): Access denied to: http://build.clojure.org/releases/org/clojure/clojure/1.3.0-alpha2/clojure-1.3.0-alpha2.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden."
"

Answer (score 1):

[Note: this is not my preferred solution, but it got my project working again].

Use Leiningen 2.7.1, which doesn't have such strict security checks. Download from: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/2.7.1/bin/lein

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to see which extension causes the problem as they can include other deps as well.

You can still download the extension though.

From the lein FAQ;
This is very insecure and exposes you to trivially-executed man-in-the-middle attacks. In the rare event that you don't care about the security of the machines running your project, you can re-enable support for unprotected repositories by putting this at the top of your project.clj file:

```
;; allow insecure downloads
(require 'cemerick.pomegranate.aether)
(cemerick.pomegranate.aether/register-wagon-factory!
 "http" #(org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.HttpWagon.))
```

For me this worked on several older project that were not updated. In the logs you can easily track which package was downloaded via http.

So this answers the : "Is it possible to disable the security" feature question from the OP.

The other question seems to have an answer on StackOverflow already. [Display complete dependency tree with Leiningen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093833/display-complete-dependency-tree-with-leiningen)